# Execute a Step based on properties file in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, jobexecutiondecider

I have to run a Spring Batch Job comprising of steps A,B,C based on properties file . I found out that we can use `JobExecutionDecider` in spring  batch . But most of the examples given are using single condition . For example

```
public class NumberInfoDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {

private boolean shouldNotify() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
    if (shouldNotify()) {
        return new FlowExecutionStatus(NOTIFY);
    } else {
        return new FlowExecutionStatus(QUIET);
    }
}
```

The above example uses only `shouldNotify()` . But in my case I need to use the same `JobExecutionDecider` to check three different properties and return the status dynamically . I need the functionality like below

```
//Properties file
StepA=true
StepB=false
StepC=false

//Program Functionality
if(stepA)
     execute StepA
if(Step B)
       execute Step B
if(Step C)
       execute Step C
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add variables and set them during bean initialization

```java
public class NumberInfoDecider implements JobExecutionDecider {

    private String stepA;
    private String stepB;
    private String stepC;

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
        if (stepA.equals("true")) {
            return new FlowExecutionStatus(A);
        } else if(stepB.equals("true")) {
            return new FlowExecutionStatus(B);
        } else if(stepC.equals("true")) {
            return new FlowExecutionStatus(C);
        }
    }
}
```

XML config

```xml
    <bean id="decider" class="com.example.NumberInfoDecider">
        <property name="stepA" value="${stepA}"/>
        <property name="stepB" value="${stepB}"/>
        <property name="stepC" value="${stepC}"/>
    </bean>
```

Or Java config

```java
    @Value(${stepA})
    String stepA;
    @Value(${stepB})
    String stepB;
    @Value(${stepC})
    String stepC;

    @Bean
    public NumberInfoDecider decider() {
        NumberInfoDecider stepDecider = new NumberInfoDecider();
        stepDecider.setStepA = stepA;
        stepDecider.setStepB = stepB;
        stepDecider.setStepC = stepC;
        return stepDecider;
    }
```